# Alfresco: override log4j2 properties

Tags: log4j2, alfresco

There are two `log4j2` properties files in the Alfresco distribution:

```
webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties
webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties
```

I need to change `appender.rolling.fileName` in both files (Tomcat can't write to the default location). Where should I do this? I feel that modifying these two files directly is probably bad practice (I'm new to Java/Tomcat/etc). Is there a standard way to modify properties?

The Alfresco docs state that you should create a custom properties file at `shared/classes/alfresco/extension/custom-log4j2.properties`. I've done this, and it works, but it creates a *third* log file, independent of the two files created by the properties above.